# Failing to start confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to setup schema registry on my windows system, it is failing with the following error message:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain
```

Tried a lot to figure out a reason, but feeling completely lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Schema Registry is not tested with Windows.

This error you are seeing indicates that the CLASSPATH is not configured correctly. [Source](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/master/bin/windows/schema-registry-run-class.bat).

Instead, it is recommended you use a Unix environment, such as WSL2, or Docker.

Comment: I tried on docker, it worked completely fine with me, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think version mismatch. For me for lower confluent version `http://packages.confluent.io/archive/6.1/` It was working. If we don't have wsl2 or linux this is may be option.